# How to obscure Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, obfuscation, security-by-obscurity

I am running a site using Wordpress as CMS System. 
Now I don't want anyone to know that this site is powered by Wordpress in the background.

Is there any easy way to completely obscure Wordpress?

The first thing I want to do is:
- Rename wp-content & wp-admin directory, respectively rename their URLs.

Maybe there is a Plugin for this?

Thanks!

Comment: This will not make your site substantially more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the footer references WordPress implements some HTML standards compliant code in the top of every page.

http://bloke.org/wordpress/cleaning-up-wordpress-header/ gives some insight about it, and plugins make comments too.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming wp-admin is a tricky process, which is, mostly, by design. There are ways around it as highlighted in this thread:

---

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/changing-the-wp-admin-url-to-whatever-i-want

---

(you'll need to follow a few links, one of which is to an example plugin as you requested - but please do read the thread and the links in it)

You are also able to easily remove all of the wp-related bits and bobs which WordPress adds to the head of your theme. Follow these links for further info:

---

http://digwp.com/2009/07/remove-wordpress-version-number/

---

and

---

http://bloke.org/wordpress/cleaning-up-wordpress-header/

---

As for moving the wp-content folder, follow the information in this link:

---

http://www.johngirvin.com/archives/moving-the-wordpress-wp-content-folder.html

---

By far and away the hardest part (and least recommended) is moving the wp-admin folder and all of the references to it.

If you are doing this simply for security through obscurity, then, well, it has limited value (see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#Security_through_obscurity ). Otherwise, good luck.

Comment: Because what annoys me are the ultra long URLs that you have to use otherwise. Like: http://www.yourdomain.com/my-blog/wp-content/themes/my-new-theme/style/style.css  I'd simple like to change it to http://www.yourdomain.com/my-blog/style/style.css

Comment: You don't (and shouldn't) need to hard code the links like that. WordPress sets up loads of defined constants for you to use. Take a look at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo as well as http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories